# Evenly spaced grid around 3 bevelled edges

Tags: bevel

any way I can have an evenly spaced grid around a shape I made from 3 bevelled edges as I’ve done in 001?

[image]

I’ve then used Unsubdivide (002) then the Wireframe modifier (003) and then Subdivision Surface (004). But it’s all distorted.

Any help is appreciated.